# ui-select dropdown box, auto size to left

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ui-select

I'm working with AngularJS ui-select, and I'm doing a multiselect dropdown, now the dropdown box's size is auto, so it's width is as long as longest selectable text. So the entire box's width is greater than inputs width. Now what I'm trying to do is to make that box go to the left side instead of right like it does by default.

```
<td style="width: 100px; vertical-align: text-top;">
                <div class="multiSelect">
                  <form name="inputForm" >
                        <ui-select ui-grid-edit-ui-select ng-required="isRequired" ng-model="dr.dir" append-to-body="true"
                            multiple search-enabled="false" close-on-select="false" hide-tags="true" hide-caret="true"
                            ng-style="{height:grid.options.rowHeight -1 }"
                            class="gridSelect multi" uis-open-close="dropdownClosedResolve(isOpen,$select);" custom-driver-multiselect="dr">
                          <ui-select-match></ui-select-match>
                          <ui-select-choices repeat="field in fields" position="auto">
                            <!-- <div ng-bind-html="field.title"></div> -->
                          <div ng-bind-html="field.title" style="margin-right: 20px"></div>
                          <div ng-class={"Ac":$select.isActive(this)} class="x-file"></div>
                          </ui-select-choices>
                      </ui-select>
                    </form>
                  <div>
              </td>
```

The CSS is default of that ui-select

Comment: Please include relevant HTML, Script, CSS and anything else to create a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There is no script, and everything is default. Asking if somebody know how do that..

Comment: I don't know what "default" means. I assume you have a specific HTML layout structure the dropdown sits in and possibly CSS/Styles already applied. If you can't include those in your post, it will be guess work how to apply the relevant CSS.

Comment: That is why I specifically said ui-select, so it wouldn't default styles means default ui-select styles. and the HTML layout of ui-select is also default. It's not really a guess work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using the bootstrap template there is a way to achieve that.

The choices list is a dropdown what means you can [change its alignment using classes](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns-alignment). So if you're on bootstrap v3.1.0 (or above), the required class is `dropdown-menu-right` alongside `dropdown-menu`:

```
.dropdown-menu-right {
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
}
```

As the `ui-select` directive does not have an attribute to control that and the `dropdown-menu` is hidden in the template we need to apply such styles manually, for example:

The style:

```
.uiselect-menu-right .ui-select-dropdown {
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
}
```

Applying in markup:

```
<ui-select ... class="uiselect-menu-right">...</ui-select>
```

**HOWEVER**

I noticed that you (like me) is using `append-to-body`, so that approach will not work. I came up then with a small directive which will add the class in the list:

```
angular
  .module("mymodule")
    .directive("uiselectMenuRight", uiselectMenuRight);

function uiselectMenuRight() {

    return {
        restrict: "C",
        link: linkFunction
    };

    function linkFunction($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        var list = $element[0].querySelector('.ui-select-choices');
        if(list)
            list.classList.add('dropdown-menu-right');            
    }
}
```

Just add that same `uiselect-menu-right` class in your ui-select and it will work.